# Apostrophes contractions and escape char issues with Outlook DASL Queries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin, apostrophe

I have a outlook plug-in that I wrote in C# it scans emails, and shuffles them around to different folders. Because the terms we search for change frequently enough that adding them as variables in the program would be totally unacceptable; on top of that the lists are quite long! 
I made it so the code slurps up rows from a CSV and uses that term to in the DASL query.

My problem is, when we need to search for words like "don't", "haven't", "shan't", "Dave's" and other contractions or possessive nouns cause issues. I have tried everything I can think of to ameliorate the issue, I am unfortunately at a loss.  The program works flawlessly unless a contraction is introduce.  Please help :)

The most relevant chunk of code is this:

```
         using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
        {
            //while != null to kill the loop
            string line;
            string prefix = @"@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription like '"; 
            string postfix = @"'";
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //slurp the csv line out, and spit it into DASL query.
                line = prefix + line + postfix;
                lines.Add(line);

            }
        } //closes out the streamreader object?
        string[] outputArray = lines.ToArray();
        return outputArray;
```

My CSV file looks something like this:

```
%i do not%
%i flipped it%
%no thanks%
```

When I try to add something like %don't do that% or %won't%, I get problems.

I've tried things like %don''t%, %"don't"%, %don/'t%, %dochr(39)t% sadly, all were unsuccessful.

How do I make the DASL query take an apostrophe?  And, how do I make it accept that apostrophe when it exists in a record in a CSV file?

Thanks :)

Edit
This is the module I'm using to search the emails with the DASL query if it can help someone nail down the problem.

```
  public void SearchEmailBodyWithArray(string[] filter)
        {
            //this is the workhorse of this program
            MessageBox.Show("Pick Source Folder");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder olFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder();
            MessageBox.Show("Pick Destination Folder");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder();
            Outlook.Items items = olFolder.Items;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

            object folderItem;
            string subjectName = string.Empty;

            int f = 0;
            while ( f < filter.Length)
            {
                folderItem = items.Find(filter[f]);
                while (folderItem != null)
                {
                    mailItem = folderItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null)
                    {
                        subjectName += "\n" + mailItem.Subject;
                        mailItem.Move(destFolder);


                    }
                    folderItem = items.FindNext();
                }
                f++;
            }
            subjectName = " The following e-mail messages were found: " +
                subjectName;
            MessageBox.Show(subjectName);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm have some DASL schema that handle apostrophes.
My piece of code is VBA, but the query probably is the same, because we are using the same namespace property schema names that the Property-Acessor object uses - as per Sue Mosher @ MS Outlook 2007 Programming: JumpStart for Admin and PwrUsers, pg 503.

```
Set myRestrictItems = myFolderContatos.Items.Restrict( _
                           "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/udfToAdd" & Chr(34) & " = 1 AND " _
                        & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:contacts:bday" & Chr(34) & " = '" & "06 de abril de 1930" & "' AND " _
                        & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:contacts:cn" & Chr(34) & " = " & ParseSpecialCharsAndDataTypeForSQL("Sérgio D'Or", False, False))
```

When I do Debug.print ParseSpecialCharsAndDataTypeForSQL:

```
?ParseSpecialCharsAndDataTypeForSQL("Sérgio D'Or",False,False)
'Sérgio D''Or'
```

And it finds the Contact:

```
?myRestrictItems.Count
1
```

Resuming, the old trick for Jet Access to escape apostrophe is the way to go.

Hope that helps.

P.S. I know that it's a lot of months since your question but, still, maybe help someone.